# how to convert $kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class); to lumen

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, lumen-5.3

I am new to laravel and lumen, I am converting laravel code to lumen. Could you please help me to convert this **make** method to lumen?

```
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
```

Comment: Can you give context to where this code is and if you have any errors from that code?